How can I sketch and find the area of a region enclosed by a graph?
Sketch and find the area of a region enclosed by the graph of f(x)=x^3-x^2 and g(x)=2x

see use-mathematica-to-calculate-the-area-enclosed-between-two-curves and define-region-between-two-curves and computing-the-area-between-two-curves

Plot[{x^3 - x^2, 2 x }, {x, -1, 2},  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
